# Android FlexboxLayoutManager recreating items

Tags: android, kotlin, flexbox, android-flexboxlayout

I am using **FlexboxLayoutManager** to display Recycler View items with dynamic width. The problem I'm facing is when the background of the item is changed it reanimates/redraw all the next items which are not very attractive/required.

[image: Screenshot of my Screen]

The following screenshot shows the use case. Whenever there are two/more items with different width in a single row, selecting/unselecting views is recreating the next neighbors.

My code for the this:

```
 val managerVal = FlexboxLayoutManager(context, FlexDirection.ROW)
// I have used these properties as well with other combinations showing here for reference
//            managerVal.alignItems = AlignItems.FLEX_START
//            managerVal.justifyContent = JustifyContent.CENTER
            itemView.rvFilterOptions.layoutManager = managerVal
val filterOptionAdapter = FilterOptionAdapter(
                context,
                record.values
            )
itemView.rvFilterOptions.adapter = filterOptionAdapter
```

I have also tried changing values in Adapter

```
val lp = itemView.llFilterValue.getLayoutParams()
            if (lp is FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) {
               lp.flexGrow = 1.0f
               flexboxLp.flexShrink = 1f
               lp.alignSelf = AlignItems.FLEX_START

            }
```

The code to change the background of the item in the adapter.

```
if (record.isSelected) {
                itemView.tvFilterValue.setTextColor(
                    AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(
                        context,
                        R.color.textWhite
                    )
                )
                itemView.ivFilterCheck.show()
                itemView.llFilterValue.background =
                    AppCompatResources.getDrawable(
                        context,
                        R.drawable.bg_dark_rectangle_circle_edge
                    )
            } else {
                itemView.tvFilterValue.setTextColor(
                    AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(
                        context,
                        R.color.textNormal
                    )
                )
                itemView.ivFilterCheck.invisible()
                itemView.llFilterValue.background =
                    AppCompatResources.getDrawable(
                        context,
                        R.drawable.bg_gray_rectangle_circle_edge
                    )
            }
```

A gif to show the behavior:

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please put part of code, how you refresh your RV, ex. with notifyDataSetChanges() method or something else.

Comment: please check the updated question

Comment: Thanks, and when ```record.isSelected``` has changed how you refreshing your adapter , you should call ```notifyItemChanged(changedPosition: Int) ```

Comment: filterOptionAdapter.setClickListener(object : FilterOptionAdapter.ClickListeners {
    override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
        filterOptionAdapter.getItem(position).isSelected =!filterOptionAdapter.getItem(position).isSelected
        
        //NotifyData
        filterOptionAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
    }

})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the fix ended up in my XML file.

***Resoning:*** When you are using the flexbox with the flex-direction **wrap** you're allowing the flexbox library to handle the view sizes. Since my use case lies in nested recycler view one of my recycler view items was using match_parent property which was causing conflicts to adjust in view at the runtime (which caused confusion at library level).

***The solution was to simply use wrap_content with flexbox to let the library take decisions for view measurements.***

Comment: how your xml look like? is it using flexbox item, or using regular card view?

Comment: regular flexbox item

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, and I think it's because I was setting a variable in the xml layout file via DataBinding in my `onBindViewHolder` function, causing the `TextView` in my layout file to be recreated. This seems to cause the layout manager to recalculate if the view should wrap or not, even if the text hadn't changed.

So I wanted to update the view without calling my normal bind function. I solved it by using `notifyItemChanged` with a payload whenever I want to mark an item as selected, for example:

```
notifyItemChanged(position: Int, payload: Any?)
```

Since you're sending a payload, you need to override

```
onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>)
```

It's important to note that this function is what the RecyclerView always calls, so if you don't have a payload, you need to call the super function, or the regular `onBindViewHolder`, e.g.:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
    if (payloads.isEmpty()) return super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
    // I know that I called notifyItemChanged with a Boolean as payload to set the selected state.
    holder.updateSelectedState(payloads.firstOrNull() as? Boolean ?: false)
}
```

Then in `updateSelectedState` I simply update the background or the imageview, and not the item (or, presumably, anything that could mess with the layout's width).

Comment: This is exactly how I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem. Fixed it by adding `setHasFixedSize(true)` to my recycler view.